# Unable to redirect url with callback in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, xss, redirect

I just create login class that check the valid user, after that user enter in his/her home section. But now i need to change the destination of the user's home conditionally, Unable to
attach switch case in url redirection.

Note: I think varibale not properly passed in function.Plz help me

My code as Follow:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('userp','',TRUE);
        }

        function index($dest) 
        {
            $this->load->view('header');  
            //This method will have the credentials validation
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
                $data['msg'] = "";
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }

            $this->load->view('footer');
        }

        function check_database()
        {
            //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            //query the database
            $password= $this->input->post('password');
            $result = $this->userp->login($email,$password);

            if($result!==FALSE)
            {
                $sess_array = array();
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                    $sess_array = array(
                        'id' => $row->id,
                        'username' =>$row->email,
                        'fname' =>$row->first_name,
                        'lname' =>$row->last_name,
                        'pic'=>$row->pic
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$sess_array);
                }

                switch($dest){
                    case 'NULL':{
                        redirect('home','refresh');   
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'part1':{
                        redirect('subhome','refresh');   
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'part2':{
                        redirect('subhome1','refresh');    
                        break;
                    }
                    default :{
                        redirect('mainhome','refresh');  
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                $data['msg'] =  "Something Wrong Username/Password";
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
                //return false;
            }
        }
    };
?>
```

Comment: $dest is declared in index($dest) but not in check_database() ,which is where your switch is attempting to use $dest.

Comment: how to pass it in check databse

Comment: If you edit config/routes.php and add a route such as $route['check_database/(:any)'] = 'verifylogin/database_check/$1' and change check_database() to check_database($dest) whatever you enter in the URL in place of (:any) will be passed to check_database as $dest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing `$dest` to the `index()` function but you are attempting to use it in your `check_database()` function.  So either you want to move your switch into the index function or you want to pass `$dest` to  `check_database()` like

```
function check_database($dest)
{
    //You can use $dest in here
}
```

If you want to pass an extra parameter to your callback function you need to put it in brackets like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database[parameter]');
```

or

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database[$parameter]");
```

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database'); @Pattle i m new in codeigniter, how can i pass dest with callback

Comment: @rbstack I've updated by answer to explain how to pass an extra parameter to your callback function